# .Net Core Extend IdentityUserRole to include Instance/Company and Extend RoleManger to take Instance

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to extend IdentityUserRole to include Instance/Company and Extend RoleManger to take an Instance in asp.net Core 3.0.

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual Instance Instance { get; set; }

}


        builder.Entity<UserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

        });
```

How do I extend UserManager to take InstanceId as well as User and RoleName?

```
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin", instanceId);
```

Comment: What's the relationships between `User` ,`Role` and `Instance/Company` ? The `IdentityUserRole ` is the join table which represents the many-to-many relationship  between `User` and `Role`. What was the effect you originally wanted to achieve? Could share more details on the models and the Implementation logic ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. So I want to be able to register users to login to separate instances/companies. I would like to achieve this by including the instance in the UserRole table. So when you add a user you add their instance/company to UserRole so they will have that role for that instance/company.

Comment: If I understand your meaning correctly , there should be a one-to-many relationship between `Instance/Company` model and `Role` model . If you want to add a role from a corresponding company to a user, you should include the instance in the `Role` table , not the `UserRole` table which is the join table of the User and Role .

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How would I then extend UserManager?